# USB thermal printer apps works when tested, but can't find a way to print a PDF, any help?

Tags: usb, printing, thermal-printer

I have a thermal printer (epson tm-t70) it works fine with Windows, but am trying to get it to work with my Android device.

I downloaded all of the first results apps after a "pos printer usb" search on google play, and all of them works when it comes to testing a print, they do detect the printer, and they do print a test.

But NONE of these apps have a way to print a PDF, they don't have an option to select a PDF, and they don't appear in the "share" menu, the only one that does is an app called "PrinterShare" but this one doesn't even detect the print.

Any help please ?

the apps that worked :

- [USB POS Printer Boost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.auco.andorid.printer.usb)
- [Quick Printer (ESC POS Print)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pe.diegoveloper.printerserverapp)
- [APP WEB IMG POS PRINTER DRIVER](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fidelier.posprinterdriver)

Comment: Technically, any non-plaintext document are converted first into their raster bitmap format. If your app supports PNG or JPG or any other image format, try to convert your PDF into that format and see what happens.